# When an app is updated in the Google Play Console (only for development) does the app have to be manually deleted

Tags: android, google-play-console

We are developing an Android app and using the Google Play Store. The app has not yet been published - we are still testing.

Our developers tell us that we have to delete the app before updating. When we haven't done that the app is all messed up.

They say that this is an artifact of only being in development, and that once we go to the store users will not have to delete the app.

I want to confirm that this is the case and there is not a different reason why the update fails.

Are others having this issue?

Comment: you definitely don't need to delete the app to re upload a new one. i just release a new build after changing the versionCode as stated below.

Comment: No need to delete the app. If you described what you call "messed up", we may be able to help a little more understanding the source of the issue. Possibly, the developers are changing the database in a non-backwards compatible way during development.

Comment: Pierre, this is exactly what I was thinking. If you change the SQLite schema of data in the app then you must detect this and upgrade the schema and data. We should get a new build tomorrow so I will test this. I am a little worried that this is the case, and we will release a build in production sometime where deleting the app would be catastrophic.

Answer (score 0):

**Production**, **Open**, **Closed**, **Internal** tracks, it is all about visibility of your app. You could manage independent any of them.

After upload apk, each added to **Artifact library**. The main rule your apk always should has distinct of the `versionCode`. Change him in build.gradle file.

When you manage track for example internal track, right now your versionCode is 10, your developers made a lot of new features, then increase version code to 11, build release apk and reupload apk to internal track. It will automatically change your current version to new version of apk. You don't need to delete old apk before upload new one.

Sorry for my broken English :)